# In getting the not a single-group group function error on this query, how can i solve this?

Tags: sql, oracle

In getting the not a single-group group function error on this query, how can I solve this?

```
select to_char(fecha_ingreso,'DY') dia,
       count(num_dept) n
  from empleados
 group by dia
```

Comment: What do you mean? You have repeated the title in the question. The title is incomprehensible. Repeating it doesn't help. Maybe show expected output so we get an idea of what you want.

Comment: Use http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ to show the sample data

Answer (score 4):

The question is too simple, you should write:

```
select to_char(fecha_ingreso,'DY') dia,
       count(num_dept) n
from empleados
group by to_char(fecha_ingreso,'DY')
```

This is because select clause is evaluated after the group by clause.